# Kafka consumer test not working on server

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, distributed-computing, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I am not able to test kafka consumer using kafka on server :-

**Scenario**

When I am testing kafka consumer using local kafka, it works fine.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --messages 1000

start.time, end.time, data.consumed.in.MB, MB.sec, data.consumed.in.nMsg, nMsg.sec, rebalance.time.ms, fetch.time.ms, fetch.MB.sec, fetch.nMsg.sec

2021-06-18 09:38:24:769, 2021-06-18 09:38:25:401, 0.9527, 1.5075, 1000, 1582.2785, 1623989305231, -1623989304599, -0.0000, -0.0000
```

But, when I am trying to test kafka in server, it is not consuming at all.

Even for 1 message it is not able to consume.

```
bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --topic connection --bootstrap-server kafka.dev.net:9092 --messages 1 --timeout 100000

start.time, end.time, data.consumed.in.MB, MB.sec, data.consumed.in.nMsg, nMsg.sec, rebalance.time.ms, fetch.time.ms, fetch.MB.sec, fetch.nMsg.sec

WARNING: Exiting before consuming the expected number of messages: timeout (100000 ms) exceeded. You can use the --timeout option to increase the timeout.

2021-06-18 09:51:27:754, 2021-06-18 09:53:07:913, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0, 0.0000, 1623990095140, -1623989994981, -0.0000, -0.0000
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this and post the output.

> kafka-console-consumer.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9096 --topic my-replicated-test-topic --from-beginning

Test Message 1
Test Message 2
Test Message 3

Comment: @ChrisDist, yes this works. I am able to produce and consume that using the above command

Comment: Looking at your command, the topic name is given as 'connection'. Are you using a right command? bin/kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --topic connection --bootstrap-server kafka.dev.net:9092 --messages 1 --timeout 100000

Comment: Yes @ChrisDist, that is the right command with all the parameters.

Comment: @EnthusiastCoder Can you mark this as a right answer, so other people can use it as a reference.